# Redirect to particular page with preg_match

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I have a search box.
When user enters a single character like ‘A’ or ‘B’ or ‘C’.
Instead of running a query on my database, I redirect them to appropriate page
of a to z directory

So for example if a user search’s for ‘H’ they get taking to www.domain.com/a_to_z/h/

To achieve this I have

```
if($_GET[search] == "a") echo header("location:/a_to_z/a/");
if($_GET[search] == "b") echo header("location:/a_to_z/b/");
if($_GET[search] == "c") echo header("location:/a_to_z/c/");
```

This works but as you can see it’s not very efficient.

I know it’s possible to accomplish this with a single line using prge_match but I don’t know how to actually do it.

Your help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The regex `[a-z]` will only match a single character from lowercase a to lowercase z. To include uppercase and numbers, use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` instead. It's probably what you're looking for:

```
if (preg_match('~^[a-z]$~', $_GET['search'])) {
    // redirect
} else {
    // handle errors
}
```

[This is a good site for the various regular expression basics.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: It works. But I will like to match both lowercase and uppercase. So far it only works for lowcase. I will also like to add 0-9 digits. Thanks again.

Comment: @jamjam Even better: the regex `\w` will match a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and the underscore (_). You could test for a match and then test for `!== '_'` if you don't want the underscore.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying I should include regex inside mysql query to "filter" out the results?

Comment: @jamjam MySQL query? What what what? Filtering would **definitely** be a good idea when making a query to the database, soo... I guess yeah. I am suggesting that.

Comment: That is not what I want to. The redirct codes is suppose to be executed before the mysql query. If the user search for a single chatacter the mysql query never runs. The query is only run if the search term is greater than 1 chatacter. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @jamjam Well, my suggestion was still only pre-redirection.

Comment: All I need to do to is edit the above preg_match to include uppercase A-Z and also numbers. Then it will be perfect.

Comment: @jamjam Then do `[a-zA-Z0-9]` instead of `[a-z]`; that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 header("location:/a_to_z/".$_GET[search]."/");
```

take on mind that $_GET[search]  isn't validated in any way here

Comment: Or, for people who don't care about security at all, this could be all you use.